# How to spcify different position of elements that belong to the same css class

Tags: html, css, angular

as shown below, i have two html elements of type `clr-dropdown-menu`.the problem i have is both of the drop-down-menus belong to the class `.dropdown-menu`. the `.dropdown-menu` contains the parameters that specify the appearance and the position of the two
html elements. when i run the code, both of the `dropdown-menu` appear at the same position as they belong to the same class `.dropdown-menu` .
i want to know how to display the two html element at different position despite they have the same `.dropdown-menu` class that contains the specifications of the position.

**element1**:

```
<clr-dropdown-menu id="idDropDownMenu" *clrIfOpen="false" clrPosition="top-left">
                        <div aria-label="Dropdown header" clrDropdownItem *ngFor="let item of overflowItems" (click)="onOverflowItemSelected(item)">
                            {{item}}
                        </div>
                    </clr-dropdown-menu>
```

**element2**:

```
<clr-dropdown-menu id="idDropDownMenu2" *clrIfOpen clrPosition="bottom-left">
                <div aria-label="Dropdown header" *ngFor="let insectiside of insectisidesArray" clrDropdownItem (click)="onInsecticideSelected(insectiside)">
                    {{insectiside}}
                </div>
            </clr-dropdown-menu>
```

**.dropdown-menu**

```
.idDropDownMenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 5rem;
    max-width: 15rem;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0.125rem rgb(115 115 115 / 25%);
    margin-top: 0.083333rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-left: 673px
}
```

Comment: To me it seems that selector `idDropDownMenu` doesn't have anything to do with positioning? Seems that component is accepting param `clrPosition` for positioning. Is that not working. Otherwise wrap `<clr-dropdown-menu>`'s in parenting div and position the div?

Comment: Your elements seem not to use any class!? Right now they are defined by their tag <clr-dropdown-menu> and by their ids "idDropDownMenu" and "idDropDownMenu2". But they do not use the class!

Comment: @EduDev but the inspector in chrom shows that the class .dropdown-menu is assigned to the two element ,,it is a built-in class

Answer (score 0):

Use the class you gave and try to wrap it in parenting div?

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
  
  <clr-dropdown-men class="idDropDownMenu" id="idDropDownMenu *clrIfOpen="false" clrPosition="top-left">
    <div aria-label="Dropdown header" clrDropdownItem *ngFor="let item of overflowItems" (click)="onOverflowItemSelected(item)">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </clr-dropdown-menu>

  <clr-dropdown-menu class="idDropDownMenu" id="idDropDownMenu2" *clrIfOpen clrPosition="bottom-left" >
    <div aria-label="Dropdown header" *ngFor="let insectiside of insectisidesArray" clrDropdownItem (click)="onInsecticideSelected(insectiside)">
      {{ insectiside }}
    </div>
  </clr-dropdown-menu>

</div>
```

```css
.idDropDownMenu {
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 5rem;
    max-width: 15rem;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0.125rem rgb(115 115 115 / 25%);
    margin-top: 0.083333rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-left: 673px
}
```